# Log implicits only for "diverging implicit expansion"s

Tags: scala, compiler-errors, implicit, scalac

Other answers suggest using `"-Xlog-implicits"` option for debugging "diverging implicit expansion" errors. However, it also logs a lot of implicits in places unrelated to these errors. Is there some way to limit it to only explain places which produce compilation errors?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If there were such an option, one might have seen it in use here:

https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/3669

But the tool of choice seems to be grep:

```
scalac -Xlog-implicits test/files/neg/t2031.scala 2>&1 | grep diverg
```

Since that area is under active development, now might be the time to submit a request for enhancement.